# Word paper design printing with white borders

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, borders, microsoft-word, paper

I've created a photoshop design for an invoice. The invoice design fits perfectly on the Word page, but when I print the exact example, it prints with white borders of 2 cm. Is there maybe an option to disable the margin so my invoice design fits perfectly on the paper?

Comment: What kind of printer are you using?

Comment: I assume you mean you're printing on a home or office printer, rather than commercially? There should be an option in your print settings somewhere but many printers simply can't print to the edge. Unfortunately such questions are off-topic here. You may be able to ask on [su], have a look for existing questions there though and have a look at their [help].

Comment: I have a Canon MG 2200 series @Lucian

Comment: As @Cai mentioned you need to play with your printer settings. If it can print margins, you need to find out how from its factory documentation. This is not a hardware support forum.

Comment: printers need a margin in order to grasp the paper for feeding, so the printable area is smaller than the sheet : https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART141963

Answer (score 2):

Your printer might be able to print on the entire paper in theory but I wouldn't recommend it. It gives a lot of trouble.

I work with printing and normally you would either print on a larger paper size and then cut it to its intended size or you would make a design with a white margin.

[image]

In your case i would either live with it, print it a little bit smaller and cut it or redesign it without color exceeding the paper.